# How to print encrypted message with correctly guess letters?

Tags: python-2.7, encryption

i am in a little rough spot with my code. I am trying to make it so once i enter a message, the message is then encrypted into  new cyphered message. Afterwards, the user is asked to make a guess of what one of the letters are, if that guess is correct, the encrypted message is then printed back out with the decrypted letter now showing correctly, as well as uppercase. My issue is keeping the decrypted letter just guessed, to permanently stay showing once the user has correctly guessed it. This is so the user can see he has guessed the letter correctly, and the message will start to reveal itself. This is my full code, and the area that i think i need assistance with is separated at the bottom.

```
import random
message1 = raw_input("Enter 50 to 150 characters: ")
message1 = message1.lower()
message2 = ""
b = ""
insults = ("You suck, try again.", "Are you this dumb?", "You're a genius. JK, idiot.", "Youre making me fall asleep." "You got this, next time, probably not.")
compliments = ("You are the best.", "How do you do it?", "Teach me senpai.", "Your IQ must be over like 150!", "I dream to be as smart as you.")
alpha = ("a", "b", "c", "d","e","f", "g","h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o","p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
cypher = list(alpha)
random.shuffle(cypher)

if len(message1)<50:
    print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
    exit()
elif len(message1)>150:
    print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
    exit()
else:
    message2= ""
    for b in message1:
        if not b.isalpha():
            message2 += b;
        else:
            message2 += cypher[(ord(b)- ord('a'))]

    print message1
    print message2
    print alpha
    print cypher


number_guess = 0
while number_guess < 25 and message2.lower() != message1:
  number_guess + 1
  guess = raw_input("Enter a guess in the form a=b:")
  guess = guess.lower()
  if len(guess) != 3:
      print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
  elif not guess[0].isalpha():
      print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
  elif not guess[2].isalpha():
      print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
  elif guess[1] != (chr(61)):
     print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
     exit()

  letter = cypher[(ord(guess[2])-ord('a'))]
  print letter
  if letter == guess[0]:
      print message2.replace(guess[0], guess[2].upper())
      print compliments[random.randint(0,4)]
  else:
      print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
```

Where I believe the issue will be resolved:

```
      letter = cypher[(ord(guess[2])-ord('a'))]
  print letter
  if letter == guess[0]:
      print message2.replace(guess[0], guess[2].upper())
      print compliments[random.randint(0,4)]
  else:
      print insults[random.randint(0,4)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your usage of *message2.replace()*. replace() doesn't modify the original string but it just returns the modified version  of the string.

You could replace with something like:

```
message2 = message2.replace(guess[0], guess[2].upper())
print message2
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very close to figuring it out, but am not sure I could have without your comment, i appreciate it!